# Where can I find more info about "Sbench"?

Tags: linux, benchmark

There's a program we are using for benchmarking our web apps that is called Sbench. Its help page shows:

```
FAST - Sbench 2.0.0.beta1 - 2008-09-13 redhat3-i686
PLATFORM   : linux2 / posix
```

However I cannot find any information about it on the web. It is producing two output files, one called .summary and one .video, but I have no idea what their format is and how they can be opened.

Any ideas what this program is?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the installation information. Do you know if the program was installed via RPM? It looks like it was distributed as a binary, though.

Try: `rpm -qf /path/to/Sbench`, where you give the full path to the `Sbench` executable.

You may not be able to find more information. It could be a utility that was developed in-house, for instance.